# Is it faster to read the first element of an array, or the 4000th?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-access

Is there any speed difference when reading from the first element of an array rather than the 4000th? Same goes for any other element in an array.

Mostly asking about c++ but any language is alright.

As for the array, it will be an array of integers.

Comment: Which language/platform? As it depends.

Comment: it depends (on a lot of things).

Comment: Write a test app and benchmark it yourself in whatever language you're using. What do the results tell you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are specifically calling an element in an array and you know the exact position in the array of the element you need to retrieve, then there will be no difference in speed.  However, if there is a loop involved, or some type of functionality that searches through the array for a specific value, then speed could be impacted.

Answer (score 2):

Should be the same. If you know index of element you are looking for, you have nothing to worry about, if not, be careful when looping through large arrays.

Depends on a language probably, but I'm sure that it's true in Java or C/C++, for the rest I really couldn't say.

Okay, now I see you are talking about C++ so you can be sure it' the same.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ is exactly the same, that's why arrays are excellent structures in order to do algorithms an a lot of things that depends on that fact.

Answer (score 1):

Accessing something in memory given an explicit address is O(1)

Accessing an array element is done by taking the starting position of the array and then adding the offset.

e.g.if arr = 0x000001f0

Access arr[0]   = 0x000001f0 + 0x00000000

Access arr[256] = 0x000001f0 + 0x00000100

**[Disclaimer: may vary by OS and virtualization and and and... -- but don't worry about that]**